# Richfaces and chart

Tags: jsf, charts, richfaces

One big piece missing on richfaces is a chart support. In my case what I need is a simple bar chart, with no interactivity to put into a jsf (richfaces 3) page, into a javaEE 6 web-application that must run only with opensource libraries
Anyone can give me some options?

thanks in advance!

note: I'm thinking on jfreechart, obviously, but what I need is something skinnable fast, with no pain

Comment: I found my solution: http://www.jenia.org/ a good component that display a generic freechart plot.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look on JSFlot .People say it works well with richfaces.

> The [JSFlot JSF chart library](http://code.google.com/p/jsflot/) builds on top of the JavaScript Open
>   Source Project Flotr (a javascript plotting library based on the
>   Prototype Javascript Framework) to create stunning interactive charts
>   purely using JavaScript. The JSFlot charting library is simple to
>   install, easy to configure and easy to use in your custom application.
>   All of the applications dependencies (purely JavaScript related) are
>   included in the Jar file.
>
> The goal of the JSFlot project is to support all the main features of
>   Flotr (Flotr has its own project page set up at
>   http://code.google.com/p/flotr/), while remaining easy and simple to
>   install and use.

Comment: Could you substantiate "people say it works well with richfaces"?

Answer (score 1):

We used JQPlot for charting in our project. Pluggable, Interactive and look good. Check them out:

[JQPlot Bar Charts](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php)